# Unable to login sitecore CMS wirh Admin username

Tags: sql-server, sitecore7

Recently i installed Sitecore CMS 7.1 Update2 and published my exsiting web site and changed connectionstrings to my old web and master db's.when i am trying to login to sitecore cms it is not allowing.i already executed below query in Core Db.Still it is not allowing me to login.

UPDATE aspnet_Membership
SET Password = '8dC23rEIsvuttG3Np1L4hJmJAOA=', PasswordSalt='joeLPwcwMq6L7kyuVfVS7g=='
WHERE UserId = (SELECT UserId FROM aspnet_Users WHERE UserName = 'sitecore\Admin')

Please let me know what is the problem?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Trying things at random or storing unrelated values to hash fields can only *guarantee* more problems. Are you sure this and the unspecified previous version use the *same* hash algorithms? Why did you even assume this has to do with the *hashes*?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing few changes  with your update in the query. you need to change IsApproved = 1  and IsLockedout=0 . Try below one and it should work.

UPDATE dbo.aspnet_Membership
SET [Password]='qOvF8m8F2IcWMvfOBjJYHmfLABc=', [PasswordSalt]='OM5gu45RQuJ76itRvkSPFw==', [IsApproved] = '1', [IsLockedOut] = '0' WHERE UserId IN (SELECT UserId FROM dbo.aspnet_Users WHERE UserName = 'sitecore\Admin')

Thanks,

Hiral shah